# Search through JSON to find sepcific values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to search a JSON from client to get specific value , linear search is working  if i go with specific keys but when i search from a key in middle of json it returns nothing.
Here is what i am trying

```
$.each(jsonStr, function (i, v) {

    var folderID = '1408614499420';
    if (v['@id'] == folderID) {
        alert(v.folder.file['@id']);
    }

});
```

I want to search a specific folder by its id and get all files in that specific folder.
Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kw99L2h/3/) with actual json.

Comment: Can you also add a sample json?

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos kindly check the Fiddle...

Comment: Yeap...Didn't think to do so... :-)

Comment: Are you trying to create a file tree?

Comment: its a kind of hierarchy of directories, each folder with its files and folder in it. I need to get specific folder by ID and show files and folders in it if there are any ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do u want something like this

```
$("#menuArea li").live('click', function (event) {
$.each(jsonStr.hierarchy.folder["folder"], function (i, v) {
    var folderID ='1408614499420';//any id of folder
   if (v['@id'] == folderID) {
        alert(v.file['@id']);//file where folder id is folderID 
    }

});
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Here's working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9kw99L2h/6/

**Edit :-**

Code for getting all subfolders & files

```
function getAllSubFolders(folder) {
    var subFolders = [];
    if (folder.folder) {
        if (folder.folder instanceof Array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < folder.folder.length; i++) {
                subFolders[subFolders.length] = folder.folder[i]['@id'];
               subFolders = subFolders.concat(getAllSubFolders(folder.folder[i]))
            }
        } else {
            subFolders[subFolders.length] = folder.folder['@id'];
            subFolders = subFolders.concat(getAllSubFolders(folder.folder))
        }
    }
    return subFolders;
}

function getAllFiles(folder) {
    var files = [];
    if (folder.file) {
        if (folder.file instanceof Array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < folder.file.length; i++) {
                files[files.length] = folder.file[i]['@id'];
            }
        } else {
            files[files.length] = folder.file['@id'];
        }
    }
    if (folder.folder) {
       files = files.concat(getAllFiles(folder.folder));
    }
     return files;
}
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9kw99L2h/9/

Comment: yes something like this, but for this i need to know the hierarchy level to get its files or folders, this json is dynamically generated from server and hierarchy levels can b different

Comment: so do u need all files inside the given folder (as array maybe??) or just the one which is inside the sub folder of given folder

Comment: just the given folder, I just want a function to which i pass the id of folder and it will return the files and id of sub-folders if there are any.

Comment: all folders and sub-folders are with id, so i want to search the folder with reference of their id

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9kw99L2h/9/ look at this fiddle ,is this what u are expecting??